# Does a different order of the same class template arguments generate a different class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template that generates a unique class by assigning properties as arguments to the template.  IE:

```
template <size_t arg> property;

template <typename... properties> class object;

object<property<value> > obj;
```

The thing I want to avoid is the compiler generating excess code based on a different arrangement of properties, such that:

```
object<property<value1>, property<value2> > obj;
```

shares the same function table as:

```
object<property<value2>, property<value1> > obj;
```

Do compilers generally have something in place to prevent duplication like this, or do I have to program in a way that forces the compiler to make the two objects share code?

Comment: How can the compiler know that your template class is symmetric with respect to the template arguments?

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not duplication, so compilers can't have anything in place to prevent it. It's only duplication if two or more type names are the same. There's nothing to say that the instantiation of `template class<A,B>` and `template class<B,A>` will be the same for any arbitrary A and B.